# How can I set up multiple virtual hosts in httpd.conf and have each use a different .htaccess file?

Tags: wamp, apache

I have many virtual hosts setup in my httpd.conf all set up like this:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/wwwWP/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName testing.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/wwwtesting/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName images.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/wwwimages/"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have commented out the #DocumentRoot line from the file. Everything works fine in my setup, but I can't figure out how to use a .htaccess file on more than one of my virtual hosts at the same time. I seem to have to change this line to the site I'm currently working on each time:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/wwwimages/">
```

It's getting a little obnoxious. How can I set up my apache to use a .htaccess file for any virtual host that has one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this SF question:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/203550/htaccess-is-ignored-even-though-virtualhost-has-allowoverride-all

Something along these lines should help:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName              intranet
    DocumentRoot            /var/www/default
    <Directory "/var/www/default">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also check this post:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/173910/in-apache-does-the-htaccess-file-override-the-httpd-conf-for-mod-rewrites

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    VirtualDocumentRoot c:/wamp/www%-2
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So I would not need any of my other virtual hosts in that file with that line? AND it would allow .htaccess to work for all the sites?! Would I need to comment out the <Directory> line or replace the path with the one you have above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will allow you to have `.htaccess` files in each subdomain folder, ie `wwwtesting/.htaccess`, `wwwimages/.htaccess`. You don't need the last two `<VirtualHost>` definitions. Just replace them with the above code. Of course you still have to modify `c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`. You can have one `<Directory>` for all your subdomains. You can specify it ahead of all `<VirtualHost>` entries.

Comment: Couldn't seem to get that to work. After replacing all of my <virtualHost> entries with the above snippet I couldn't get apache to restart. I also don't get where i would specify what each of the ServerNames would be.

Comment: You don't need `ServerName`. The code automatically maps `images.local` to `c:/wamp/wwwimages`. You need to activate `mod_vhost_alias` in your Apache `httpd.conf`.

Comment: hmm, this seems so simple compared to what I have. I have activated the vhost_alias module in wamp - I'll have to play with it some more to try and get activated. Thanks for the help!